# How to match start of string and insert characters depending on the number format google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I require the script to run so that if the string Strats with the number "7" then +44 is entered at the start of the string. I the string starts with the number "8" then +353 is entered at the start of the string. Then if the string already has "+" at the start then there is no change made.
Have the following script however it requires modification.

```
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  let lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  let numOld = ss.getRange(2, 12,lastRow-1,1).getValues();
   //var paymentTypeRange = sheet.getRange(2, 14, sheet.getLastRow() -1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 

numOld.forEach((r,i) =>{ 

console.log(r[0])
  let newnum = []

  //delete "-" in phone number and push in newnum array
  //Or use other REGEX in replace, it's up to you.
  numOld.map(data => {
    newnum.push(data[0].toString().replace(/[-]/g, ''))
  })
  if(  r[0].match(/^7/) ){
  //push "+44" in after position 0 in text and then join with ''
  let pushdatanum = newnum.map(d => {
    return [d.slice(0, 0), '+44', d.slice(0)].join('');
  })

ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  
  //insert back to Sheet1 begin at row2 col3, numRow from pushdatanum.lenght, numColum from pushdatanum[0]. 
  //length
  ss.getRange(2, 3,pushdatanum.length, pushdatanum[0].length).setValues(pushdatanum);
  }
  if(  r[0].match(/^8/) ){
  //push "+353" in after position 0 in text and then join with ''
  let pushdatanum2 = pushdatanum.map(d => {
    return [[d.slice(0, 0), '+353', d.slice(0)].join('')];
  })
  

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  
  //insert back to Sheet1 begin at row2 col3, numRow from pushdatanum2.lenght, numColum from pushdatanum2[0]. 
  //length
  ss.getRange(2, 3,pushdatanum2.length, pushdatanum2[0].length).setValues(pushdatanum2);
}})

  return false
}
```

The spreadsheet can be viewed at
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SK-JfdTjNDQb4csWP9Jg845r-6AJAuVjlzsfppGBrmI/edit?usp=sharing
Column L has the input numbers and column C has the correct output numbers.
Any Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: Use Array Manipulation

A simpler way of doing what you want is to treat the phone numbers as an array. You need to split the numbers into individual digits using the `split()` function. Afterwards, check for the first digit if it is 7, 8, or '+'. Then, you can use the `unshift()` function to add '+44', and '+353' for numbers with 7 and 8 as first digits, respectively. You may use the script below as a basis:

```
function addPrefix() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var col = 1; //change to 12 when applied to column L
  var data = ss.getRange(2, col, lr - 1, 1).getValues();
  var output = data.map(x => x.map(y => {
    var array = y.split("");
    if (array[0] == 7) {
      array.unshift("+44");
      return (array.join(""));
    }
    else if (array[0] == 8) {
      array.unshift("+353");
      return (array.join(""));
    }
    else if (array[0] == '+') {
      return (array.join(""));
    }
  }))
  ss.getRange(2,2,lr-1,1).setValues(output);
}
```

### Output

[image]

References:

- [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [unshift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)
- [join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Comment: Feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.